# Inheritance with factory method/class pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was reading about different methods of object creation in JavaScript instead of using `new` and ES6-classes. One method is using the factory method/factory class pattern (taken from https://medium.com/humans-create-software/factory-functions-in-javascript-video-d38e49802555):

```
const dog = () => {
  const sound = 'woof'
  return {
    talk: () => console.log(sound)
  }
}
const sniffles = dog()
sniffles.talk() // Outputs: "woof"
```

How would I implement a class like `Animal` or rather another factory funtion which my dog function can "inherit" from? Would I pass the animal object to the dog function and set the prototype of the object being returned to the passed animal object?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve exactly? You might not need inheritance.

Comment: Just use extends: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

Comment: Just asking in general but for example the Animal class could implement behaviour which all of its subclasses would want to implement. Or a method like move() which would be overwritten in some of the subclasses.

Comment: Because this is not the “factory pattern” I’m looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use `Object.create`:

```js
const animal = () => ({
  talk: function() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
});

const dog = () => Object.create(animal(), {
  sound: {
    value: "woof"
  }
});

// or...

const dog2 = () => {
  var someDog = Object.create(animal());
  someDog.sound = "woof";

  return someDog;
};

var someDog = dog();
someDog.talk();

var someDog2 = dog2();
someDog2.talk();
```

BTW, my opinion is that you should go with ES2015+ class/inheritance and leave the use of custom factories and `Object.create` for corner cases where you really need them:

```js
class Animal {
  talk() {
    return console.log(this.sound);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.sound = "woof";
  }
}

var dog = new Dog();
dog.talk();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant! :)

Comment: @eol No problem! ;)

Comment: Great answer, although I think factory functions are always preferable to classes or constructor functions. I think Eric Elliot's articles sums up the reasons why this is the case nicely: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e

Comment: @ChristosDimitroulas I'll check it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

I checked this issue because I decided to use Factory Functions instead of classes.
I assume you have a general factory function, like `Animal` or `Mammal`, which has some characteristics (such as sound, like some suggested), and you want to inherit them and add some specific characteristic in another factory function.

Let's build an Animal factory function:

```js
const Animal = ({color = "green", numberOfLegs = 4} = {}) => {
  const SetColor = (newColor) => {
    color = newColor;
  };
  const GetColor= () => color;
  const GetNumberOfLegs = () => numberOfLegs;
  const MakeSound = () => console.log("Screetch");
  return {
    GetColor,
    GetNumberOfLegs,
    MakeSound
  }
}
const newCreature = Animal({color: black, numberOfLegs: 3})
newCreature.MakeSound() // -> "Screetch"
```

And let's build a Dog factory function:

```js
const Dog = ({name = "rex", color = "black", numberOfLegs = 4} = {}) => {
  const MakeSound = () => console.log("Woof Woof");
  const Roll = () => console.log(`${name} made a roll!`)
  return {
    MakeSound,
    Roll
  }
}
const sniffles = Dog({name: "sniffles", color: black, numberOfLegs: 4})
sniffles.MakeSound() // -> "Woof Woof"
sniffles.Roll() // -> "sniffles made a roll!"
```

---

What should I do if I want to inherit all the good things I get from `Animal` that I have already?
**Using ES6 [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) helps us to achieve a very neat way of doing so:**

```js
const Dog = ({name = "rex", color = "black", numberOfLegs = 4} = {}) => {
  const anAnimal = Animal({color, numberOfLegs}); // used the Animal factory!
  const MakeSound = () => console.log("Woof Woof");
  const Roll = () => console.log(`${name} made a roll!`)
  return {
    ...anAnimal, // And That's where magic happens!
    MakeSound,
    Roll
  }
}
const sniffles = Dog({name: "sniffles", color: black, numberOfLegs: 4})
sniffles.GetNumberOfLegs() // -> 4
sniffles.MakeSound() // -> "Woof Woof"
sniffles.Roll() // -> "sniffles made a roll!"
```

**So what actually happened?**
In `Dog` factory we invoked the `Animal` factory into *anAnimal*, so anAnimal is now an object.
In the object that `Dog` factory returns, we spread the anAnimal object, and after that added properties of `Dog`.
If you give an Object two identical keys with different values, it will take the latter:

```js
const someObject = {a: 1, b: 2, a: 3};
someObject // -> {a: 3, b: 2}
```

Therefore, you don't need to worry if `Dog` uses any keys that were given already from `Animal`, because they are overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

@nils is right, it's not clear what/why you want to inherit, so I'm just guessing, but maybe this is what you mean :)

```js
const animal = (sound) => {
  return {
    talk: () => console.log(sound)
  }
}
const dog = () => animal('woof')
const sniffles = dog()
sniffles.talk() // Outputs: "woof"
```

Comment: It's a possible approach

Answer (score 1):

In addition to these other answers, I'd recommend taking a look at this excellent book on Javascript design patterns, [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

In particular, take a look at its chapter on [factories](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript).

To achieve inheritance in a factory pattern, its original factory class accepts a configuration object. More specific factories just extend the original factory class by passing in objects.